# vim: Copy from vim to any program, but not include carriage return\tab characters?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

Not sure if this is possible, but I have "set list" on so I can see all of the line feed characters.

This is awesome, but when I copy and paste (with the mouse) from vim to another program it picks up all the formatting characters.

For example if I copy from the console to google docs I get this:

```
function getMember(obj) {$
^IarrMembers = [];$
^Ifor(var propertyName in obj) {$
^I^Iif(typeof obj[propertyName] === 'function') {$
^I^I^I$
^I^I^Ivar reflect = {$
^I^I^I^Itype : 'method',$
        name : propertyName,$
        value : obj[propertyName]$
^I^I^I}$
^I^I} else {$
^I^I^I^Ivar reflect = {$
^I^I^I^I^Itype : 'Property',$
^I        name : propertyName,$
^I        value : obj[propertyName]$
^I^I^I^I}$
^I^I}$
^I^IarrMembers.push(reflect);$
^I}$
^Iconsole.table(arrMembers);$
}$
```

Is it possible to copy text right from the console without getting these characters? I guess I can always open it another editor for this if I have to, but I was just wondering if this is possible.

-- should mention I'm on V7.4 on Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are copying "what is on the screen" you get all that information. You should be able to copy from vim into the clipboard and just paste it normally. Check out [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard) for more information.

Sounds like you want to do `gg"*yG` (in vim) to copy everything into the system buffer and then you can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> (paste) it where ever without the formatting.